# US Federal Income Tax: 3.8 % Investment Tax owed if Deductions are greater than AGI?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, irs, investment-income

For 2021, my charitable deductions were much greater than my AGI.  I think all I owe to the Feds on Income Tax for 2021 is the 3.8% tax on Investment Income.  Correct?  Or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is correct, even if you elect to apply charitable contributions deduction to up to 100% of your AGI (something that is allowed in 2021 specifically), the deduction would still be added back into the Modified AGI for the purposes of NIIT (See [26 CFR 1.911-6](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/26/1.911-6)).

Comment: Where is there a 100% limit for 2021? There was one for 2020, in CARES PubL 116-136 sec 2205, but I've not heard of, or seen on the IRS website, any for 2021. There is a nonitemized charitable deduction for cash up to $300/$600 for 2021 in TCDTRA PubL 116-260 div EE sec 212. Also 1.911 is about the Foreign Earned Income Exclusion and irrelevant here; more to the point AGI, and thus MAGI for NIIT, is computed before any itemized deductions are taken.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 See here: https://www.irs.gov/newsroom/expanded-tax-benefits-help-individuals-and-businesses-give-to-charity-in-2021

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 as to MAGI, then 26 USC 1411(d)(2) refers to Sec. 911(d)(6) with regards to MAGI calculation for NIIT: https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/26/1411

Comment: (1) I see on the other Q you pointed to CAA in 2020 (but div N not div EE) which is further back than I searched, and I wouldn't call that recent in Sept. 2021, but yeah, good enough. (2) 1411(d) refers to both 911(a)(1) and (d)(6). It adds back any income excluded by (a)(1) _less_ any _AGI_ deductions or exclusions disallowed under (d)(6) _related to the income in (a)(1)_. OP has no FEI&HE income in (a)(1), thus there can be no related deductions or exclusions; and if there were, the charitable deduction is not 'taken into account in computing adjusted gross income' so ...

Comment: ... it still wouldn't be included in the amount in para (2), and if it _were_ unitemized and thus included in para (2) it would not be added back but rather _subtracted_ from the add-back done in para (1) (i.e. it would be re-allowed).